# Adding lines and polygons on tablet with no right click button on the stylus

Tags: pyqgis

How do I end the digitizing of a line or polygon without a right click button on the stylus of a tablet.

If there is no built-in method I can create a button on a widget to either send a right-click action or some other code to complete the digitizing of the line.

I've no idea how to send a right click command in Python. I've tried the following to add the feature but it adds a new feature instead of committing the partially digitized feature.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feat = QgsFeature(layer.pendingFields())
iface.openFeatureForm(layer, feat, False, True)
```

Comment: might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973188/emit-and-catch-double-click-signals-from-qgsmapcanvas